# How to remove root user from php mail from address

Tags: php, email

I'm implementing a reporting mail in php. I'm using simple php mail function with header information as below:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Daily Report <info@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n".
            'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$subject = "Report for Domain on ".date('Y-m-d');
$message = "Hello World Testing this mail function.";
$to = "alauddin.xxx@xxx.com";

if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else  {
    echo "Message sent at ".date("Y-m-d H:i");
}
```

Mail is working fine (I'm receiving this email) but the problem is that From Address is coming weird like:

```
On gmail:
Daily Report <info@mydomain.com> via mailgun.org

On outlook:
info=mydomain.com@mailgun.org on behalf of Daily Report <info@mydomain.com>
```

I think from address is coming with root user address

but I'm looking like:

```
Dail Report <info@mydomain.com>
```

Please guys help me. I've already spent almost 6 hours to resolve this over the internet... :(

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem, you're sending it in the code with from-field "info@mydomain.com" and you're getting "info@mydomain.com" in your inbox.. looks fine to me.

Comment: No, actually the problem is "mailgun.org" is coming with from address.
it looks weird in outlook (info=mydomain.com@mailgun.org on behalf of Daily Report <info@mydomain.com>)

Comment: Maybe your mail server adds this, check it's ini files.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of settings should I change in php.ini or in any other file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailgun is an e-mail service. The reason why `mailgun.org` keeps showing up in your e-mail header is because your domain isn't verified.

[Verify Domain Info/Instructions](http://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain)